# Swapping columns in specific blocks

Tags: awk, swap

I hope all you guys have a great new year!

I am trying to swap 2 columns in a specific block of a file. The file format is:

```
Startpoint: in11 (input port)
Endpoint: out421 (output port)
Path Group: (none)
Path Type: max

Point                                    Incr       Path
---------------------------------------------------------------
input external delay                     0.00       0.00 r
in11 (in)                                0.00       0.00 r
Ckt432/A[7] (TopLevel432b)               0.00       0.00 r
Ckt432/M1/A[7] (PriorityA)               0.00       0.00 r
Ckt432/M1/U7/Y (INVX1_RVT)               0.03       0.03 f
Ckt432/M5/U12/Y (OA21X1_RVT)             0.10       2.44 r
Ckt432/M5/Chan[3] (DecodeChan)           0.00       2.44 r
Ckt432/Chan[3] (TopLevel432b)            0.00       2.44 r
out421 (out)                             0.00       2.44 r
data arrival time                                   2.44
---------------------------------------------------------------
(Path is unconstrained)

Startpoint: in37 (input port)
Endpoint: out421 (output port)
Path Group: (none)
Path Type: max

Point                                    Incr       Path
---------------------------------------------------------------
input external delay                     0.00       0.00 r
in37 (in)                                0.00       0.00 r
Ckt432/A[5] (TopLevel432b)               0.00       0.00 r
Ckt432/M1/A[5] (PriorityA)               0.00       0.00 r
Ckt432/M1/U8/Y (INVX1_RVT)               0.03       0.03 f
Ckt432/M1/U13/Y (NAND2X0_RVT)            0.06       0.10 r
Ckt432/M5/U12/Y (OA21X1_RVT)             0.10       2.44 r
Ckt432/M5/Chan[3] (DecodeChan)           0.00       2.44 r
Ckt432/Chan[3] (TopLevel432b)            0.00       2.44 r
out421 (out)                             0.00       2.44 r
data arrival time                                   2.44
---------------------------------------------------------------
(Path is unconstrained)
```

I am trying to

1. Replace 5th column with 2nd column. If a letter in 5th column is `r`, this would be replaced with `v`. If a letter in 5th column is `f`, this would be replaced with `^`.
2. insert two double quotation marks in 1st column.
3. replace 3rd column with `;`
4. replace 4th column with `//`

This should only be done in blocks which are defined starting and ending lines - `input external delay` , `data arrival time`.

Additionally, I want to change texts before/after the block with predefined texts.

My expected output should be:

```
$path {
  // from: in11
  // to: out432
  $name "test_1" ;
  $cycle 1 ;
  $slack -0.130978 ;
  $transition {
 "in11"  v  ; //  (in)
 "Ckt432/A[7]"  v  ; //  (TopLevel432b)
 "Ckt432/M1/A[7]"  v  ; //  (PriorityA)
 "Ckt432/M1/U7/Y"  ^  ; //  (INVX1_RVT)
 "Ckt432/M5/U12/Y"  v  ; //  (OA21X1_RVT)
 "Ckt432/M5/Chan[3]"  v  ; //  (DecodeChan)
 "Ckt432/Chan[3]"  v  ; //  (TopLevel432b)
 "out421"  v  ; //  (out)
  }
}

$path {
  // from: in11
  // to: out432
  $name "test_2" ;
  $cycle 1 ;
  $slack -0.130978 ;
  $transition {
  "in37"  v  ; //  (in)
  "Ckt432/A[5]"  v  ; //  (TopLevel432b)
  "Ckt432/M1/A[5]"  v  ; //  (PriorityA)
  "Ckt432/M1/U8/Y"  ^  ; //  (INVX1_RVT)
  "Ckt432/M1/U13/Y"  v  ; //  (NAND2X0_RVT)
  "Ckt432/M5/U12/Y"  v  ; //  (OA21X1_RVT)
  "Ckt432/M5/Chan[3] "  v  ; //  (DecodeChan)
  "Ckt432/Chan[3] "  v  ; //  (TopLevel432b)
  "out421"  v  ; //  (out)
  }
}
```

Currently, I can swap columns, but I don't know how to use them only in the block. My code is:

```
awk ' { c1 = $1; c2 = $2; $1 = " \" "; $2 = c1; $3 = " \" "; $4 = $5; $5 = " ; // "; $6 = c2; print; } ' file1.txt
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which one is the 5th column? i only see 3 colums in the table

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue!

Let's implement it step by step, first extract the data of interest

```
$ awk '/data arrival time/{f=0} f; /input external delay/{f=1}' file

  in11 (in)                                0.00       0.00 r
  Ckt432/A[7] (TopLevel432b)               0.00       0.00 r
  Ckt432/M1/A[7] (PriorityA)               0.00       0.00 r
  Ckt432/M1/U7/Y (INVX1_RVT)               0.03       0.03 f
  Ckt432/M5/U12/Y (OA21X1_RVT)             0.10       2.44 r
  Ckt432/M5/Chan[3] (DecodeChan)           0.00       2.44 r
  Ckt432/Chan[3] (TopLevel432b)            0.00       2.44 r
  out421 (out)                             0.00       2.44 r
  in37 (in)                                0.00       0.00 r
  Ckt432/A[5] (TopLevel432b)               0.00       0.00 r
  Ckt432/M1/A[5] (PriorityA)               0.00       0.00 r
  Ckt432/M1/U8/Y (INVX1_RVT)               0.03       0.03 f
  Ckt432/M1/U13/Y (NAND2X0_RVT)            0.06       0.10 r
  Ckt432/M5/U12/Y (OA21X1_RVT)             0.10       2.44 r
  Ckt432/M5/Chan[3] (DecodeChan)           0.00       2.44 r
  Ckt432/Chan[3] (TopLevel432b)            0.00       2.44 r
  out421 (out)                             0.00       2.44 r
```

add the column replacement, separate sections, etc.

```
$ awk '/data arrival time/{f=0;print""}
             f{sub("r","v",$5);
               sub("f","^",$5);
               print $1,$5 " ; // " $2 }
    /input external delay/{f=1}' file

in11 v ; // (in)
Ckt432/A[7] v ; // (TopLevel432b)
Ckt432/M1/A[7] v ; // (PriorityA)
Ckt432/M1/U7/Y ^ ; // (INVX1_RVT)
Ckt432/M5/U12/Y v ; // (OA21X1_RVT)
Ckt432/M5/Chan[3] v ; // (DecodeChan)
Ckt432/Chan[3] v ; // (TopLevel432b)
out421 v ; // (out)

in37 v ; // (in)
Ckt432/A[5] v ; // (TopLevel432b)
Ckt432/M1/A[5] v ; // (PriorityA)
Ckt432/M1/U8/Y ^ ; // (INVX1_RVT)
Ckt432/M1/U13/Y v ; // (NAND2X0_RVT)
Ckt432/M5/U12/Y v ; // (OA21X1_RVT)
Ckt432/M5/Chan[3] v ; // (DecodeChan)
Ckt432/Chan[3] v ; // (TopLevel432b)
out421 v ; // (out)
```

now, capture input, output and add quotes to the first fields

```
$ awk -v q="\"" '/Startpoint:/{input=$2}
                   /Endpoint:/{output=$2}
           /data arrival time/{f=0;print""}
                             f{sub("r","v",$5);
                               sub("f","^",$5);
                               print q $1 q, $5 " ; // " $2 }
        /input external delay/{f=1; print input; print output}' file

in11
out421
"in11" v ; // (in)
"Ckt432/A[7]" v ; // (TopLevel432b)
"Ckt432/M1/A[7]" v ; // (PriorityA)
"Ckt432/M1/U7/Y" ^ ; // (INVX1_RVT)
"Ckt432/M5/U12/Y" v ; // (OA21X1_RVT)
"Ckt432/M5/Chan[3]" v ; // (DecodeChan)
"Ckt432/Chan[3]" v ; // (TopLevel432b)
"out421" v ; // (out)

in37
out421
"in37" v ; // (in)
"Ckt432/A[5]" v ; // (TopLevel432b)
"Ckt432/M1/A[5]" v ; // (PriorityA)
"Ckt432/M1/U8/Y" ^ ; // (INVX1_RVT)
"Ckt432/M1/U13/Y" v ; // (NAND2X0_RVT)
"Ckt432/M5/U12/Y" v ; // (OA21X1_RVT)
"Ckt432/M5/Chan[3]" v ; // (DecodeChan)
"Ckt432/Chan[3]" v ; // (TopLevel432b)
"out421" v ; // (out)
```

so on.  I guess you can add the static values around the data based on the template...